# Loading image from http request

Tags: http, dart, flutter, filemaker

I'm developing a profile card that has to get different value's. I'm getting all the value's but i also want to load a network image. I'm using a filemaker server and i had noticed that i needed coockies to load this. When i make a request copy paste the image url into my browser it just loads. But whenever i'm loading it into my application i get the 401 statusCode with my image.

I have tried just a valid network image that's working, i have readed something about coockies but i'm not sure if i need to use them and how. I also find it weird that whenever i load the image in my browser it works but not on my application.

Future makeRequest() async {
    var url4 =
        "https://fms.xxxxxx.nl/fmi/data/v1/databases/Roscom Management Systeem/layouts/medewerker pa api/_find";
    var body = json.encode({
      "query": [
        {"Emailadres(1)": "xxxx@xxx.nl"}
      ],
    });

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  "Authorization":
      'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
};

var response = await http.post(url4, body: body, headers: headers);
setState(() {
  var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  data = responseJson['response']['data'][0];
  profielfoto = data['fieldData']['iMedewerker Foto'];

  print(profielfoto);
});
```

[Value i get in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN3qV.png)

I expect that i can load the image in a networkimage with just the var $profielfoto. I don't know what to do with the coockies or maybe there's a much easier way to do it. I hope someone can help me please let me know if i need to provide more information about the server or anything else. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things. Please do not put any type of heavy processing in setState

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to
>   wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might
>   be associated with the change. For example, here a value used by the
>   build function is incremented, and then the change is written to disk,
>   but only the increment is wrapped in the setState:

`setState` tells the widget when it needs to be redrawn

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image

```
String _profilePhoto = "";
//Change await into an async operation
http.post(url4, body: body, headers: headers).then( (response) {
   var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);


   print(data['fieldData']['iMedewerker Foto']);
   setState(() {

      _data = responseJson['response']['data'][0];
     _profilePhoto = data['fieldData']['iMedewerker Foto'];
   });
})

Widget build(BuildContext context){
      //Check if string is empty
     if ( _profilePhoto == "" ){
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
     }else {
           return Image.network( _profilePhoto );
     }
}
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image

You have two choices to grab images from the network. I believe I presented one way.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I have tried that, it doesn't work i still get the 401 statuscode.
I/flutter (13994): Exception: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 401,

I mentioned something about coockies maybe someone with filemaker server knows how to load the image's. I will look into it myself but haven't found anything that worked :(

I have mentioned something about coockies i hope someone knows if that's it. I have a libary but i don't know how to implement it into my own code. I'm just hoping someone knows if this is the solution or maybe there's another solution.

Answer (score 0):

the authorization token must be the issue. a secure server will return this token when a user logs in. then all ensuing  request must have this token in the 'authorization header'. if it is not there or incorrect the server returns a 401